# Make linkable ring signatures shorter?

Tags: signature, implementation

I need a way to make the signatures shorter, currently with a ring size of **1000 members** I get a signature size of **34000 bytes**, this is too big for me I need a way to make it smaller.

I tried compressing the signature with **gzip** but it only makes it bigger, the only other solution I can think of is to use other linkable ring signatures schemes like "**Short Linkable ring signatures**". The only problem with this, however, is that there are no implementations of these schemes on the internet.

- Do you have any idea how can I decrease the signature size?
- Or do you know of any implementation of shorter linkable ring signatures schemes?

Comment: The question is too broad. Can you please put a reference about the scheme that are you adopting? Further, what is the scenario? Did you find something related to the Constant Size Ring Signature?